# How to Parallel Download Using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I have a page full of links from an external server. once I click on any link, it gets redirected to the dowanload.php where I use cURL command and download begins. But the problem is that I need to wait till the active connection(download) finishes and then the second link I already clicked begins download.

How can I tel the cURL to allow multi connection instead of queuing?

Having said that if I download the links directly from the browser, the external server allows me to do so as much as simultaneous download I want so that means there is no any limit sets from the external server.

I tried many different cURL headers but none of the worked.

Also, if I use three different browsers at a time I can download three files at the same time meaning that the cURL does its job so maybe there is a cURL header to tel the browser allow downloading multiple files at a time.

Here is how my download.php looks like:

```
$url = ($_GET['data']);
$filename = ($_GET['filename']);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($url));
header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=$filename");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How about using `multicurl`?

Comment: It's not a batch download. I go through the links and click the ones I want one by one.

Comment: It's probably just the session blocking you. Try `session_write_close()` right at the top of your file.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Yes, it works when I disable the session at the beginning of the file but I need to check the user's session to make sure the link is not shared with someone else and comes from the main page and the same browser. Any advice how I can disable the session before the cURL and reenable it with the same session value instead of killing it?

Comment: You can't re-enable it once it's closed. Make all the checks on the session before you start curl, use `session_write_close()` then start curl. This way the long operation will not block you.

Comment: Could you also advise how I can force the cURL to download the file instead of opens it in browser?